# Does Wildfly 14 support OpenJDK 11 or any other version of OpenJDK?

Tags: java, wildfly

What are the various OpenJDK versions supported on Wildfly 13 and Wildfly 14 ?
Can someone provide me the support matrix if any ?

Answer (score 1):

I work on WildFly 14 and Open JDK 11 - no problems so far.

Comment: As well as any other openjdk version 8 and up